# How to use CELL function inside OFFSET function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying below formula:

```
OFFSET(CELL("address"), 0, -2, 1, 1)
```

Instead this works:

```
OFFSET($P$20, 0, -2, 1, 1)
```

I do not have the cell reference and so have to compute in formula itself. How to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Niraj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to replace $P$20 by a string you compute, use

```
.... INDIRECT(function) ....
```

where function returns an A1-style or R1C1-style address (in the latter case you specify a second arg FALSE

Comment: Yes, using INDIRECT it works: 'OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address")), 0, -2, 1, 1)'